# Unable to install Openshift RHC tools

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am new to OpenShift and I'm trying to install RHC gems with:

```
$ sudo gem install rhc
```

which show up are successfully installed, however by the time it installs the documentation the process does not seem to end. By this point I rum

```
$ sudo rhc setup
```

And it does not recognise the command. I have Ruby and Git both running on my mac so I do not understand why it does not work.

Something that I am missing?

EDITED:

It seems to get stuck in the documentation installation:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ User$ gem install rhc
Fetching: net-ssh-2.9.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: net-scp-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: net-ssh-multi-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: highline-1.6.21.gem (100%)
Fetching: commander-4.2.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: httpclient-2.4.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: open4-1.3.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: rhc-1.25.2.gem (100%)
===========================================================================

If this is your first time installing the RHC tools, please run 'rhc setup'

===========================================================================
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.9.1
Successfully installed net-scp-1.2.1
Successfully installed net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0
Successfully installed net-ssh-multi-1.2.0
Successfully installed archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2
Successfully installed highline-1.6.21
Successfully installed commander-4.2.0
Successfully installed httpclient-2.4.0
Successfully installed open4-1.3.4
Successfully installed rhc-1.25.2
10 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.9.1...
Installing ri documentation for net-scp-1.2.1...
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-multi-1.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing ri documentation for highline-1.6.21...
Installing ri documentation for commander-4.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for httpclient-2.4.0...
Installing ri documentation for open4-1.3.4...
Installing ri documentation for rhc-1.25.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.9.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-scp-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-multi-1.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for highline-1.6.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for commander-4.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for httpclient-2.4.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for open4-1.3.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for rhc-1.25.2...
MacBook-Pro-2:~ User$
```

Comment: `sude` ? It's a typo, right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry asking this question on my mobile on the road.

Comment: I'll edit it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it installed fine, you need to now run the `rhc setup` command to finish setting things up.  What do the command `rhc setup` or `rhc --version` show as the output?

When your terminal returns to the `MacBook-Pro-2:~ User$` prompt, that means that it is done installing successfully.

Also, if you are using RVM or RBENV, then you don't need to `sudo gem install rhc`, or else rhc is being installed to your system ruby, and when you run `rhc setup` as your user, which is using rvm or rbenv, then it will not be in your path.  Try running `gem install rhc` as just your regular user and see what it says.  If you can run `rvm --version` as your regular user and get output instead of an error, this is most likely your issue (or a similar command with rbenv...

I also edited your command above to be in the correct order.

Comment: I would second this query in terms of confirming whether the process is truly broken. I'd be interested if everything was fine after `rhc setup`.